# how to decode UTF8 string in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding

I want to decode an UT8 encoded string.

The input string is "**Ã¸Ã¦-test-2.txt**"

and after decoding it should become 
"**øæ-test-2.txt**"

I found many API to encode the NSString or NSData to UT8 (NSUTF8StringEncoding) but was not able to find the way to decode it.

What I have tried until now:-

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:[strToDecode cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

AND

```
[strToDecode stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

AND

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[strToDecode cStringUsingEncoding:[NSString defaultCStringEncoding]]]
```

I have tried the same input string and I get the proper output in [third party decoder](http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode).

But was not able to get success

Any hint in right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code. Show us what you've done so far. Any solution we offer is going to use those standard APIs, so we need to know where you're going wrong.

Comment: i have a same problem if you solved this than please share solution with me.

Comment: for me the solution was


NSString *decodedString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[encodedString cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]];

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]
```

Comment: I have edited my question. Please check my input and verify the output that I have mentioned.

Comment: How are you getting input string? It should be stored in NSData or char* to successfully read it as utf-8, otherwise it will be messed up.

Comment: I get the response as an xml. The xml parser returns me the values in Dict. which is there in string format. what can be done in this case ?

Comment: I have tried the same input string and I get the proper output in third party decoder. so I guess the string conversion would not be an issue.
http://www.cafewebmaster.com/online_tools/utf_decode

Comment: Try to check are there any encoding property in xml parser.

Comment: Can you give me some e.g. were I can encode and decode the same string. Like suppose I am encoding a japanese character(with some API) and then decode it(with some API) and get the same result.

Comment: But how do I convert string to bytes?

Answer (score 7):

I use [this](http://www.dev-smarter.com/decode-an-utf8-nsstring/) one.

```
NSString *encoded_string = @"Ã¼";
const char *ch = [encoded_string cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
NSString *decode_string = [[NSString alloc]initWithCString:ch encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"%@",decode_String)
```