# Saving Chinese characters to SQLite Database

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios5, utf-8, localization

Im having some problems saving chinese characters into the SQLite Database running behind my app.

Ive logged the variables before saving them and they are fine, but in the db they look like -> `â°ÂªÃ±â°â«â«`, so its definitely a saving issue. Im converting the text to UTF8String when its saved as well. `[variable UTF8String]`.

Comment: Is the program in objective-c?

Comment: yeah, sorry, i didn't make that clear. for iOS5+

Comment: I am not really familiar with objective-c, so I can only be of limited help.  It looks like possibly a double-encoding or an encoding mismatch.  What does it look like if you save to the database without explicitly encoding?

Comment: Also, perhaps this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669132/how-to-decode-utf8-string-in-iphone

Comment: What if you read back the values? In the database there are just raw bytes, and if you open it using the wrong editor, you won't see Chinese characters. Maybe query the DB and assign the result to the text of a `UILabel` to see if it works.

Comment: H2CO3 - I use SQLite DB Browser to check the db, when i save english values to the db its fine, its only the chinese characters that error, and I'm reading it back from the db to Labels with the same error.

Comment: Nathan - Ive fixed the issue, thanks for the help! it was an error with the UTF8String encoding. I was under the impression you have to do that to save to the db, but apparently not. I was passing the value into the db as a `%s` and sending it the value `[variable UTF8String]`, but I've changed it to `%@` and just sending the variable as is.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same problem.Use adLongVarWChar as your datatype to the column in SQLite.It is definitely gonna save and retrieve your Chinese character or any other language character .