# How to decode special characters in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, decode, encode

I am newbie to iphone development and working on a demo app,In that i am getting a string like "abc%26def",I want to decode this type of text to actual test,I know its very basic question but still i couldn't find any solution from link,So can anybuddy pls help me for this?

**my code is as below**

```
 if(i%3==0)
                {
                    [dataDictionary setValue:[dataDictionary valueForKey:TRIPPER__KEY] forKey:CONTENT_KEY];
                    [dataDictionary setValue:CELL_TEXTFIELD_TRIPPER_COUNT forKey:@"cellIdentifier"];
                }
                else if(i%3==1)
                {

                    //*name = [(NSString *)self stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "];
                    NSString *name = [[dataDictionary valueForKey:NAME_KEY] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    [dataDictionary setValue:name forKey:CONTENT_KEY];
                    [dataDictionary setValue:CELL_TEXTFIELD_TRIPPER_NAME forKey:@"cellIdentifier"];
                    [dataDictionary setValue:@"Triper Name" forKey:@"placeHolder"];
                }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669132/how-to-decode-utf8-string-in-iphone is it useful to you?

Comment: please don't use `valueForKey` with dictionaries. Use `objectForKey` or `dataDictionary[NAME_KEY]`. `valueForKey` doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work for sure

```
NSString *str = @"abc%26def";   //put any string that you want
NSCharacterSet *setToKeep = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"];
NSCharacterSet *setToRemove = [setToKeep invertedSet]; //inverted set will have all other remaining symbol, char etc
NSString *newString =[[str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:setToRemove]componentsJoinedByString:@""]; //this is the decoded string
NSLog(@"%@",newString);
```

Comment if you need something more than this, I ll modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**use this:**

```
NSString *name = [dataDictionary valueForKey:NAME_KEY];
```

**instead of:**

```
NSString *name = [[dataDictionary valueForKey:NAME_KEY] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

**update**

```
[[dataDictionary valueForKey:NAME_KEY] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: it gives me result like this jigar%26makwan

Comment: mean name is  gives you   jigar%26makwan on [dataDictionary valueForKey:NAME_KEY]?

Comment: yes exactly frend.thing is that i am getting this respnse from the remote server and i want to decode them to actual character,means "%26" should be convert to "&" a"%20" for white space ...etc

Comment: ohk let me try this one

Comment: It give me "jigar%25%26makwana"